# In the given figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram then prove that $\triangle ABE=\triangle BCE$
[image]

Attempt 
$$\triangle ABD=\triangle CBD$$
$$\triangle ABD=\frac {1}{2}||gm ABCD$$

Now what should I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw a line AP and a line CQ that are perpendicular to DE.

$\triangle ADE=\frac{AP\times DE}{2}$

$\triangle CDE=\frac{CQ\times DE}{2}$

$\triangle BCE=\frac{AP\times DE}{2}-\triangle CDB$

$\triangle ABE=\frac{CQ\times DE}{2}-\triangle ADB$

Since ABCD is parallelogram, $\triangle CDB=\triangle ADB$

Since $\triangle ADP$ is congruent with $\triangle CBQ$, $AP=CQ$.

Therefore, $\triangle BCE=\triangle ABE$.

[image]

Comment: How do you get the area of BCE and ABE

Answer (score 1):

Slightly easier. Connect $AC$. Let the intersection of the two diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ be $M$.$\triangle MAD \equiv \triangle MCB$ is easily shown. Hence the altitudes of these triangles to the bases $MD$ and $MB$ are equal. $\triangle ABE$ shares the same altitude as $\triangle MAD$ and $\triangle BCE$ shares the same altitude as $\triangle MCB$ with respect to the common base $BE$. Since $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle BCE$ have equal altitudes and a common base, they have equal areas.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triangle $\triangle ADE$.
The segment $AB$ divides $\triangle ADE$ into two triangles,
$\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ABE$, whose areas are in the ratio
$$
\lvert\triangle ABD \rvert : \lvert\triangle ABE \rvert = BD : BE.
$$
This is a fact whenever you subdivide a triangle in this way,
and it is a consequence of the fact that all three triangles
$\triangle ADE$, $\triangle ABD$, and $\triangle ABE$
have bases along the line $DE$ and have the same altitude from
vertex $A$ to those bases.

A similar argument regarding the triangle $\triangle CDE$ tells us that
$$
\lvert\triangle CBD \rvert : \lvert\triangle CBE \rvert = BD : BE.
$$

Two ratios that are equal to $BD:BE$ are equal to each other, so
$$
\lvert\triangle ABD \rvert : \lvert\triangle ABE \rvert
  = \lvert\triangle CBD \rvert : \lvert\triangle CBE \rvert.
$$

This implies 
$$
\lvert\triangle ABE \rvert : \lvert\triangle CBE \rvert
  = \lvert\triangle ABD \rvert : \lvert\triangle CBD \rvert.
$$

But since $\lvert\triangle ABD \rvert = \lvert\triangle CBD \rvert$,
this implies that
$\lvert\triangle ABE \rvert = \lvert\triangle CBE \rvert$.